# Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

My SDK version is "Latest" which means 4.2 and the other thing is set to 3.0.  App Loader is giving me this error.

Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK.

XCode Version 3.2.5

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly try moving the deployment target (other thing) to 3.1 instead of 3.0.  XCode 3.2.5 is the latest version, you could also try a re-install if nothing else works.

Comment: I changed it to 3.1 and it works.  THANKS GUYS!  All your answers helped me in understanding the issue.  Special thanks to Kendall.  Apparently Apple is not accepting apps that work on 3.0 and older anymore.

Comment: I thought I remembered reading somewhere that recently they shifted to only taking 3.1 apps, but I could not find supporting evidence so I didn't want to claim that was the problem for sure.  Glad it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 6):

Set your `Base SDK` to `Latest iOS` and your `Deployment Target` to 3.0. Make sure you do a `Clean Build` and then try submitting. Also, make sure this is the case for the Target as well. Right-Click on Target and choose Get Info, and set the same parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have some prerelease installed? Beta, GMSeed1? Had the same error with a "old" GMSeed Build. Check if you really have the newest one.